# Sync music between iOS and NAS

Tags: ios

I have a jail broken iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1, along with a music library that I constantly update. So far, it has become a pain syncing the music between the NAS and my iPhone - I would have to do it every time I add a new song to the music folder.

Is there a piece of software that is preferably free, or extremely cheap that I can install on my iOS device to sync music between a folder on my NAS and my music library? This should be one way, meaning if I was to delete a piece of music on my iPhone, it would not delete it on the NAS, and if a piece of music was deleted on the NAS, the app will not delete it from my iPhone. I would prefer to have it sync once every xyz hours, and I should be able to manually check for updates with a button or something.

Thanks